# dropdown menu size changed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a possibility to trigger an event via jQuery / JavaScript when the size of a dropdown menu has changed / an element is added to it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot detect if a new option has been added to a select.

There is no event that will announce you if a new option has been added to the select.

A simple solution to this problem would be to create an interval that checks every n seconds for new options.

Example:

```
 var leSelect     = $('#my-select'),
     noOfoptions  = leSelect.children().length;

 setInterval(function() {
     if(leSelect.children().length > noOfoptions) {
         console.log('boom. new option has been added');
     }
 }, 10000); // 10 seconds
```

Comment: thx for the answer. unfortunately i need this information directly after size change.

Comment: Well if this information is so important you could reduce the interval time to 100-500ms. Simple huh?